# I want to check files which are uploaded today in s3 and check if the files are more than 1 hour

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I want to create a lambda that will monitor a s3 bucket for every one hour.
the conditions for the lambda should be like:

If files are uploaded today lambda should take the list of objects and check if the lastmodified is more than 1 hour from now.

if no files are uploaded today, lambda should do nothing.
I tried below code, but it gives me all the older files. I don`t want lambda to check files that are uploaded yesterday or any previous to that. It should only check those files that are uploaded today and tell me if the files are older than 1 hour from now.

I don`t want s3 event notification.

Please help me how to achieve this

```
import boto3
import os 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from dateutil.tz import tzutc, UTC

TOPIC_ARN = 'mysnstopicarn'

s3_resource = boto3.client('s3')
sns_resource = boto3.resource('sns')
sns_topic = sns_resource.Topic(TOPIC_ARN)

lessthan = []
greaterthan = []
result = []

listobjects = s3_resource.list_objects(Bucket='mybucketname',Delimiter='Archives')['Contents']

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    for key in listobjects:
 
        if key['LastModified'] < datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(hours=1):
    
          lessthan.append(key['Key'])

    for i in lessthan:
      path, filename = os.path.split(i)
      result.append(filename)
    final = list(filter(None, result))

    sns_topic.publish(Message=f"This object {final} is more than one hour old")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the the most recent files, so you should look for `LastModified` values ***greater than*** your target date.

```py
# if LastModified is greater than (not less than) the target
if key['LastModified'] > datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(hours=1):
```

Comment: ```if key['LastModified'] > datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(hours=1):